# How to change the fontsize for everything inside QTextEdit in PyQt4?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qtextedit, qtextcursor

I have a `QTextEdit` widget whose contents are populated programmatically using `QTextEdit.textCursor`.

My plan is to let the user view the populated information in the `QTextEdit`, edit the text if necessary, and later print to a PDF file using `QPrinter`.

However, I would like to change the font size of the entire contents of the `QTextEdit` before allowing the user to edit the text. I just need to set the contents to a single font size; there is no need to accommodate multiple font sizes.

I have tried using `QTextEdit.setFontSize(16)` both before and after the `textCursor` operation but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

How do I change the font size of the contents of a `QTextEdit` widget?

Comment: Is http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtextedit.html#setFontPointSize works as you want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found full solution. You should:

- remember current `textCursor`
- call `selectAll`
- call `setFontPointSize`
- call `setTextCursor` to clear selection

In C++ it can be done with the following code(it is just example but it solves your problem):

```
QTextCursor cursor = ui->textEdit->textCursor();
ui->textEdit->selectAll();
ui->textEdit->setFontPointSize(32);
ui->textEdit->setTextCursor( cursor );
```

Comment: Only selectAll() then setFontPointSize() can take effect.

Answer (score 16):

Functions like `QTextEdit.setFontPointSize` work on the *current format*. If you want to change all the font sizes at once, you need to set the size of the base font, like this:

```
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(16)
    self.editor.setFont(font)
```

Note that you can also change the *relative* size of the base-font using the [zoomIn](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#zoomIn) and [zoomOut](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#zoomOut) slots. The implementation of those slots changes the base-font size in exactly the same way as shown above.

Comment: After setPointSize, zoom have no effect ! Can not use both in the same time?

Comment: @sonichy. It works fine for me. You must be doing something different somehow. Maybe you could try with different font-family? It could be that some fonts aren't scalable.

Comment: how do you know that QTextEdit.setFontPointSize work only on the current format ? No description of this behavior in the doc http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setFontPointSize

Comment: @iMath. The docs say: "Sets the point size of the current format".